# Entity Framework in Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have solution with 3 projects:

1) - library
2) - test (windows forms application)
3) - windows service

Library uses Entity Framework. When i link it to test application it works. My App.config (for test application) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="ITSBPEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.0.131;initial catalog=ITSBP;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
 <startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
 </startup>
 <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I've referenced to library in service also. I installed it and run, but when it try to use Entity Framework some exception is thrown, there is log:

> The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

App.config in service project is copy-pasted from test application. EntityFramework.dll exists in debug folder.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll and EntityFramework.dll at output dir?

Comment: What is in the app.config for the service?

Comment: @Uriil - EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll was missing, I didn't notice that there is such file. Problem solved, thank you